# NestJS Testing Module can't mock HttpModule

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jestjs, nestjs

It is strange because the ConfigModule seems to mock as expected. Not sure how a circular dependency could be the issue here as it is not possible for HttpModule to import my service?

error:
Nest cannot create the RootTestModule instance.
The module at index [1] of the RootTestModule "imports" array is undefined.

```
Potential causes:
- A circular dependency between modules. Use forwardRef() to avoid it. Read more: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency
- The module at index [1] is of type "undefined". Check your import statements and the type of the module.
```

Code:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [ConfigModule, HttpModule],
  providers: [
    LightCastService, 
    {
      provide: CACHE_MANAGER,
      useValue: mockCacheManager,
    },
    {
      provide: ValueRepository,
      useValue: mockValueRepository,
    }, 
  ],
}).compile();

service = module.get<LightCastService>(LightCastService);
mockHttpService = module.get<HttpService>(HttpService);
mockConfigService = module.get<ConfigService>(ConfigService);
```

});

Comment: If this is for a unit test, I would suggest not having `imports` at all and ust providing custom providers to mock the dependencies

Comment: Tried this, still getting a circular dependency if I mock the HttpService.

Comment: That _probably_ means you're getting an `undefined` value. Can you show your imports?

Comment: import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { ValueRepository } from '@value/value.repository';
import { LightCastService } from './light-cast.service';
import { CACHE_MANAGER } from '@nestjs/common';

Comment: Note the above imports were adjusted per your suggestion to remove the import statement and mock the services instead

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. By any chance do you have a GitHub repository that shows this?